# Find the max/min value in a pair of columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

My data looks like this:

```
df <- tribble(
    ~A, ~B,     
    0.2, 0.1,
    0.2, 0.3,
    0.5, 0.1,
    0.7, 0.9,
    0.8, 0.9,
    0.4, 0.2)
```

How might I select the max/min value between `A` and `B`?

Desired Output:

```
   A    B    C  
1  0.2  0.1  0.2
2  0.2  0.3  0.3
3  0.5  0.1  0.5
4  0.7  0.9  0.9
5  0.8  0.9  0.9
6  0.4  0.2  0.4
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could try `pmax`

```
mutate(df, C=pmax(A,B))
#      A   B   C
#1 0.2 0.1 0.2
#2 0.2 0.3 0.3
#3 0.5 0.1 0.5
#4 0.7 0.9 0.9
#5 0.8 0.9 0.9
#6 0.4 0.2 0.4
```

`max` gets you the `maximum` single value of the two columns instead of the "row" maximum

Comment: @user3731467 I recommend accepting his answer by clicking on the tick mark if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: The question's only been up for five minutes :)

Comment: @Avinash I will in 8 minutes!